# .each() add an attribute to a parent from jquery to js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am a newbie in js and jquery and need help with rewriting  my code from jquery to pure js.

I've got several parent divs. Each of them have a child div inside.

I want to add a class to both child and parent, but to parent as an attribute value in data-name.

Class names are stored in an array, in other words first parent and its child will get a array[0] class name, second parent and its child - array[1] class name, etc.

I use this jquery for this

```
$(".back").each(function(i) {
    $(this).addClass(tile_array[i]);
    $(this).parent().attr("data-name", tile_array[i]);
});
```

I tried to rewrite it in js like this:

```
var backs = document.querySelectorAll('back');
for (let i = 0; i < backs.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < tile_array.length; j++) {
        backs[i].classList.add(tile_array[j]);
        backs[i].parentNode.setAttribute("data-name", tile_array[j]);
    }
}
```

However, this does not work. How should I rewrite my code so that it works properly?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're have a typo - a missing class selector in `querySelectorAll('back')`

Comment: Beside the typo @RoryMcCrossan pointed out, I'm guessing you also don't want all things from the `tile_array` applied to each of the individual "backs" so if you remove the inner loop and use `tile_array[i]`, you should have a 1 to 1 mapping of elements to classes from the array, no?

Comment: You also don't need second `for (let j = 0; j < tile_array.length; j++) {`

Comment: $(this).parent("div').attr("data-name", tile_array[i]);

Comment: Thank a lot all who contributed!!! I corrected the typo and delete an inner loop! And everything works perfectly! You are rocking, men!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this : `backs.length` and `tile_array.length`  are same .so no need ah inner loop

```
for (let i = 0; i < backs.length; i++) {
        backs[i].classList.add(tile_array[i]);
        backs[i].parentNode.setAttribute("data-name", tile_array[i]);
   }
```

***And*** add  a class in `querySelectorAll('.back')`

Answer (score 0):

You can skip the inner loop - you don't use it in your jQuery, why would you do that here?

Also, to set `data` attribute there is [`.dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes) element property in Javascript. So your final code would be like:

```
var backs = document.querySelectorAll('back');
for (let i = 0; i < backs.length; i++) {
  backs[i].classList.add(tile_array[i]);
  backs[i].parentNode.dataset.name = tile_array[i]
}
```